# Caret position changes to end on backspace.how can i restore the caret position on deleting a word from the middle the sentence.?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, contenteditable

i have content editable div and it has a character limit of 420 words and it works fine but on reaching the word limit when i try to delete a character from the middle, the caret moves to the end of the sentence.
below is my code.

```
 <div id="newmessage" onClick={(e)=>e.stopPropagation()} ref="newmessage" data-placeholder="Post your ideas"  className={cx(styles['message-box'],bootstrapStyles['bg-white'],styles['is-placeholder'])}  
                    contentEditable 
                    onInput={this.emitChange}
                    onPaste={this.onContentPaste}
                    onFocus={this.openFullBox}
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.html}}
                  >

  emitChange=(event)=>{
      // debugger
      if(!this.props.auth.user){
        this.setState({warning:"Please sign in to post your message"})
        this.refs['newmessage'].innerHTML = '';
        return 
      }
      var value = event.target.innerText;
      const  {previousValue}  = this.state
      const reg = new RegExp(/\s{1,}/) 
      let prevValArr = previousValue.split(reg)
      let tags= [...this.state.multiAssets,...this.state.multiUsers]
      tags.forEach(x => {
        const isPresent = value.split(reg).includes('@'+x.value)
        if(!isPresent && prevValArr.indexOf('@'+x.value)>=0){
          this.setState({
            multiAssets: this.state.multiAssets.filter(m => m.value !== x.value),
            multiUsers: this.state.multiUsers.filter(m => m.value !== x.value),
    
          })
        }
      })
      

      if(value.includes("@") || value.includes(" ") ){
        this.setState({   
          queryStart:true
        })
      }
      

      if(value.length==0){
        event.target.innerHTML=''
        //this.changeCursor(event.target)
        this.setState({   
          possibleOptions:[],
        })
      }

      this.checkMessageLength(event.target)

      if(this.state.queryStart && value.includes("@")){
          let lastWord = this.getLastWordTyped()
          if(lastWord!==null && lastWord.startsWith('@')){
            let  queryValue = lastWord.slice(1)
            
            this.getSuggestionsList(queryValue)
          }
          else{
            this.setState({
              queryStart:false,
              possibleOptions:[]
            })
          }
          return this.setState({
            queryStart:false,
          })
      }
    }

    getLastWordTyped=()=>{
      var selection = getSelection();
      var line = selection.getRangeAt(0).endContainer.nodeValue;
      var cursor = selection.focusOffset;
      var lastWord = ''
      var words=[]
      if(line){
         words = line.substring(0, cursor).trim().split(' ');
      }
      if(words.length>0){
         lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
      }
      return lastWord
    }

    changeCursor(contentEditableElement){
      // debugger
      console.log("editable called",contentEditableElement)
      var el = document.getElementById("newmessage")
      let range = document.createRange();
      let selection = window.getSelection();
      range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
      range.collapse(false);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
    
    checkMessageLength=(contentEditableElement)=>{
      // debugger
      let value =contentEditableElement.innerText
      const user = this.props.auth.user
      let tags= [...this.state.multiAssets,...this.state.multiUsers];
      if(value.length==0){
        contentEditableElement.classList.add('is-placeholder')
        this.setState({
          warning:''
        })
      }else{
        contentEditableElement.classList.remove('is-placeholder')
      }

      let newvalue=value;
      let count = 0
      tags.forEach(x => {
        let pos = value.indexOf(x.value)
        while(pos !==-1 ){
          count += x.value.length
          pos = value.indexOf(x.value,pos+1)
        }
      })

      if(user){
          let role=user.role
          let permission = userPermissions[role]
          
          if( value.length-count > permission.limit){
            this.setState({
              warning:'Maximum allowed character limit is '+permission.limit
            })
            newvalue = value.slice(0,permission.limit+count) + '<span class="excess-content">'+value.slice(permission.limit+count,permission.limit+count+20)+'</span>'
            newvalue = this.highlightTags(newvalue,tags) 
            contentEditableElement.innerHTML = newvalue
            this.changeCursor(contentEditableElement);
          }else{
            this.setState({
              warning:''
            })
          }
      }else{
          if(value.length-count > 150){
            this.setState({
              warning:'You have reached maximum character limit'
            })
            newvalue = value.slice(0,140+count) + '<span class="excess-content">'+value.slice(140+count,count+160)+'</span>'
            newvalue = this.highlightTags(newvalue,tags) 
            contentEditableElement.innerHTML = newvalue
            this.changeCursor(contentEditableElement);
          }
          else{
            this.setState({
              warning:''
            })
          }
      }
      this.setState({
        message:newvalue,
        previousValue:value

      })
    }
```

the message length is being measured in function checkMessageLength and if the message if crossing the word limit the function changeCursor is being called which moves the cursor position to last but if i am trying to delete a word from the middle when the length has crossed the limit the caret position moves to end on every character deletion and it is creating a problem in middle of the content if i want to delete them.

can anyone please help me with this.any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why move the cursor position at all?

Comment: @iamdlm if i am using backspace for word "try" in the sentence "let me try this" the cursor moves to end. of "this" after every character i backspace in "try".so i need to restore the cursor position to the word "try" when i am editing it.